# Why does the trace of the pion operator vanish?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, group-theory, trace, pions

I am working my way through Srednicki's QFT book.  Currently I'm in chapter 94.

Between equations 94.20 and 94.21, Srednicki says that the following expression vanishes in the case of two light flavors of quarks:

$$Tr(U(x) - U^\dagger(x))\qquad(1)$$

Where

$$U(x)=exp[2i\pi^a(x)T^a/\mathit(f_\pi)]\qquad(2)$$

with $\pi^a(x)$ being a pion field and $T^a$ the associated generator.

Am I right in figuring that the reason the trace vanishes in the case of two light flavors of  quarks is because in that case we're working in $SU(2)$ and the generators, $T^a$ form a complete set of traceless matrices?

Or am I wrong (very possible)?

Comment: You understand how the [exponential of the Pauli vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector) explicit expression leads you to the answer for Pauli matrices (only)?

Comment: Fixed the typo.  Can  you help me out and explain a little bit more re. the Pauli vector here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed (1) vanishes for SU(2), but not, in general, for other SU(N)s, where the generators also span the space of traceless hermitian matrices! Here, as your text points out, the generators are proportional to the Pauli matrices, a very special set.

Exponentials of Pauli matrices ([Pauli vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector)) are remarkably simple:
$$
e^{i a \hat n \cdot \vec{\sigma}}=1\!\! 1 ~\cos a+ i\hat n \cdot \vec{\sigma}~\sin a,
$$
the antihermitean part of which is traceless, so (1) vanishes.

(In your case, $2i\vec\pi\cdot \vec{T}/f_\pi\equiv ia ~~\hat n \cdot \vec{\sigma}$.)

Note this is a special feature of SU(2): it has a vanishing symmetric d-coefficient in its algebra; unlike, e.g., for SU(3) whence the above exponential is not *that* simple... but still [tractable](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0034-4877(15)30040-9); don't worry about it, really; merely note the cubic term in the expansion of the exponential, $\propto i\operatorname{Tr}( (\vec\pi\cdot \vec T)^3)$, fails to vanish!

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos, "but not, in general, for other SU(N)s", are you sure?

Comment: @MadMax compute the term cubic in the generators for anything past SU(2), e.g. SU(3). What do you find? Not to mention the reference linked.

Comment: @MadMax. For SU(3), $d_{jkl} = \frac{1}{4}\operatorname{tr}(\{\lambda_j,\lambda_k\}\lambda_l)\neq 0 $.

Comment: @CosmasZachos, thanks! Good to know. I didn't realize that before! Seems to me for general SU(N), Eq. 1 holds for N even, but not for N odd. Is it correct?

Comment: You mean the vanishing of (1)? No. The d-coefficients of su(N) certainly do not vanish for even N>2.

Comment: @CosmasZachos, my reasoning is that SU(N) $\subset$ SO(2N), and the 2N-dimentional pseudoscalar is Hermitian for N even and anti-Hermitian for N odd. It seems to me that the anti-Hermitian part of $Tr(U(x))$ in (1) has something to do with the 2N-dimentional pseudoscalar. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: You may see from [this basis of su(4)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3896743/can-every-su4-matrix-be-written-as-a-product-of-of-these-4-matrices) that the anticommutator of $I\otimes \sigma^1$ with $\sigma^2\otimes \sigma^1$ does not vanish, but is proportional to $\sigma ^2 \otimes I$, another generator.

Comment: I think I am wrong: for any N>3, one can just simply use the non-zero $d_{jkl}$ from su(3) to illustrate that (1) is non-vanishing, since su(3) $\subset$ su(N) after all.

Comment: Of course. To my knowledge, *d* coefficients are non vanishing for all N>2.